# Checking if character is newline

Tags: delphi, pascal

Hello i'v got simple program which is couting characters in given text until line is empty line only with new line

```
var
  znaki: array['a'..'z'] of integer = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
  napis: String;
  maly: String;
  dlugosc: Integer;
  znak: char;


begin
napis := 'a';
while napis[1] <> '#13#10'do
begin
  readln(napis);
  maly:=LowerCase(napis);
  for dlugosc:=(length(maly)) downto 1 do
begin
znaki[maly[dlugosc]]:=znaki[maly[dlugosc]]+1;
  end;
  for znak:='a' to 'z' do
    writeln(znak, ' ', znaki[znak]);
  end;

end.
```

it fails on while condtion and i dont know why. 
Pleas give me clue

Comment: You can also replace your incrementation by this `Inc(znaki[maly[dlugosc]]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One char, napis[**1**]; can't be 2 chars **#13** & **#10**...

So, I'll do this for example:

```
var
  znaki: array['a'..'z'] of integer = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
  napis: String;
  maly: String;
  dlugosc: Integer;
  znak: char;


begin
napis := 'a';
while ((Length(napis) > 0)) do
begin
  readln(napis);
//  napis := StringReplace(napis, #13#10, #10, [rfReplaceAll]);  //useless for a console readln
  maly:=LowerCase(napis);
  for dlugosc:=(length(maly)) downto 1 do
  begin
    znaki[maly[dlugosc]]:=znaki[maly[dlugosc]]+1;
  end;
  for znak:='a' to 'z' do
    writeln(znak, ' ', znaki[znak]);
end;
end.
```

Comment: i dont know if checking napis[1] <> '#10' is necessary i made it like while length(napis) <> 0

Comment: I agree... for a console app... this is not

Comment: I have a question regarding your code... maybe delphi expert can explain me... I don't understand why this line works `znaki[maly[dlugosc]]:=znaki[maly[dlugosc]]+1;` when I type "spaces", numbers, ... as this should violates the subrange bounds... any link/explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

`#10` is line feed

`#13` is carriage return (i.e. move to beginning of line)

You only need to check for #10.