# Using the `in` keyword causes "E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds" in Delphi

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-2009

I've come across some rather unusual behaviour in a bit of Delphi code. When using the `in` keyword to check if an item is in a constant array, I get the following compilation error:

> E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds

The constants are defined as follows:

```
type TSomeEnum = (seFoo = 1000,
                  seBar = 2000,
                  seBoo = 3000,
                  seFar = 4000,
                  seFooBar = 5000,
                  seBooFar = 6000,
                  seLow = 1000,
                  seHigh = 6000,
                  seCount = 6);
```

The line that is failing is the following:

```
if someObj.someProperty in [seFoo, seFar, seFooBar] then
...
```

Whilst I understand the reasoning behind the error showing in [another question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599685/e1012-constant-expression-violates-subrange-bounds-why-does-it-work-with-varia), where bounds checking on integer arrays wasn't done at compile time when using a variable, it seems odd that I'm getting the same problem with a constant array which is most certainly within bounds.

For now, I've replaced the line with a (much larger) statement comprising of `or` clauses. However, this is clearly not ideal. Can anyone shed any light on why I'm getting this problem?

Comment: @TLama I'm not sure I understand the logic here. Why would the *value* of the items cause a failure, rather than the *number of items*?

Comment: Ordinal values must be in the 0..255 range..

Comment: Use `case someObj.someProperty of seFoo,seFar,seFooBar:` instead.

Comment: Once you care about the ordinal values of an enum, they aren't really enums anymore, in my view. This is a mis-feature borrowed from C/CC which doesn't have enumerated types. You don't have to use it! One the other hand, the limited ability of Delphi sets is also sometimes glaring. Only 255 elements. Bah!

Comment: +1 for a well-written question (the problem is presented well), although in fairness I should mention that I would downvote this if it was given as an answer to a question instead. (That's an awful misuse of sets, especially the last three values.)

Comment: Ooh, I had not looked at the names of these *enums* but Ken is bang on. Your approach is certainly wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan they are enums with explicitly assigned ordinality, documentation is good here - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types#Enumerated_Types_with_Explicitly_Assigned_Ordinality

Comment: @Serg From the compiler's perspective yes. From a developer's perspective, those are not enums.

Comment: From any perspective the above is subrange [6..6000]

Comment: @Serg Well, that doesn't look like the perspective of the developer does it. Look at those meaningful names. Or do you think about enums purely by considering their ordinal value?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree that OP enum looks strange, I will never write such a code, but it is a documented language feature. If you think of enum values in terms of their ordinals you are thinking about a subrange, not a pure enumeration.

Comment: @KenWhite I totally agree that it's non-standard to include those last 3 values. Unfortunately this product was written 20+ years ago, and we have a lot of code style and internal functions that rely on such values being available. At a few million lines of legacy code, it's non-trivial to alter and provides little benefit.

Comment: @Polynomial 20 years ago, enumerated values with specified ordinal value did not exist. They were added in D6 to support Kylix dev. So what you say doesn't ring true. Someone clearly modified the existing program and added this abomination!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 20 years ago I hadn't even used a computer, so I wouldn't know. There was only one developer here back when D6 came about, so I'd imagine it's his doing. No comment on that one ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Documentation about [`Sets`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types) says :

> The base type can have no more than 256 possible values, and their ordinalities must fall between 0 and 255.

So even if you can have enums of any value, the `if xx in [a,b,c]` statement will fail here, since a set cannot hold a value larger than 255.

Use a case statement instead:

```
case xx of
  a,b,c : // Make something 

end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative response. I like the `case` trick - much cleaner!